# Max Likelihood Estimators of a stable Gaussian VAR$(p)$ process. Are the Lutkepohl formulas correct?

Tags: econometrics, time-series

In «New Introduction to Multiple Time Series», page 90, we have the following formulas for the ML estimators of a stable Gaussian VAR$(p)$ process:

[image]

where $\tilde \alpha = vec(\tilde A_1,...,\tilde A_p)$.

And here is exactly where my doubt resides. If for $\tilde \alpha$ estimator, I need $\tilde \mu$ estimator, but then for $\tilde \mu$ I'm going to need also $\tilde \alpha$. So, how is this dependence broken, or is this solved by an iterative algorithm that will reach a fixed point?

I've also posted [this question in CV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/331104/mle-in-a-stable-gaussian-varp-process-are-the-lutkepohl-formulas-correct), but I didn't get any answer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the difference between $\tilde{\mu}$ and $\tilde{\mu}^*$?

Comment: @caverac their dimension, only.  Both are vectors, with the same vector $\mu$ repeated. $\tilde \mu^*$ is $TK\times 1$, the other is $Kp\times 1$.

Comment: I will look into this, need a bit more context. Will come back to you later this week